# How can I paste text by pressing the left and right mouse buttons at the same time?

Tags: 12.04, shortcut-keys, mouse

I am coming from Ubuntu 10. I just recently upgraded to 12.04 LTS.

In 10, I use to be able to cut and paste from Terminal by selecting text, and just pressing my two mouse buttons.

In 12.04, I can't seem to do this. I have to highlight text, then right click to copy, then right click to paste.  Or, I can do <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd>. Both are okay methods, but not as fast as before.

How do I configure Ubuntu to preserve 'old-school' cut and paste?

Answer (score 3):

Clicking the scroll wheel does not work on a two button mouse =)

The feature you are wanting is called "middle button emulation" and is not enabled out of the box as of Ubuntu 11.04 or so (not sure).

IMO easiest method is to install [gpointing-device-settings](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gpointing-device-settings) [image: Install gpointing-device-settings]

```
sudo apt-get install gpointing-device-settings
```

You then 'use wheel emulation'

[image: screeny]

There is a longer discussion on this bug report if you wish to manually edit xorg.conf

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-evdev/+bug/710762