# Cannot paste by pressing left and right button at the same time

Tags: mouse

I am running version 16.04.2 version of Ubuntu and Unity Desktop and have my touch pad disabled in System Settings. My mouse has 2 buttons and a middle wheel.

When I highlight something and press the middle wheel, whatever was
highlighted gets pasted as expected.

But, pasting also used to work when I press the left and right button together. This is no longer working. When I press the left and right buttons together what comes up is the popup menu which has 'Open Terminal'.

Looking at [How can I paste text by pressing the left and right mouse buttons at the same time?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140828/how-can-i-paste-text-by-pressing-the-left-and-right-mouse-buttons-at-the-same-ti), it seems like I need to enable middle button emulation by running the
`gpointing-device-settings` command.

This command is no longer found in the latest version of Ubuntu.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/783229/is-gpointing-device-settings-in-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Used the above and installed libgpds0 and gpointing-device-settings, and enabled middle button emulation and my problem is solved. Thanks.

Comment: Seemed to work before but not after reboot.  Running gpointing-device-settings now produces two identical errors in the console: An X Error occurred. The error was BadAtom(invalid Atom parameter).  In the device settings window that comes up, I have 'Use middle button emulation' checked and 'Use wheel emulation' unchecked.

Comment: Maybe look at some of the command line options at http://askubuntu.com/questions/160164/how-do-i-enable-middle-mouse-button-emulation-in-12-04-lts

Comment: Also see http://askubuntu.com/questions/456452/ubuntu-14-04-how-to-set-middle-mouse-emulation-no-taps-real-buttons

Comment: The above link helped. Created /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/middle-mouse-button.conf and rebooted and paste works fine after reboot. Thanks.